# no error on lack of namespace qualifiers in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm working on a small C++ project and ran into some behavior regarding namespaces that looks really weird to me. I've defined all my classes and functions in a namespace `my_project`:

```
// point.hpp:
namespace my_project {
    template <size_t dim> class Point { /* snip */ };
}

// convex_hull.hpp:
namespace my_project {
    std::vector<size_t> convex_hull(const std::vector<Point<2> >& xs);
}
```

I then went to write a test for everything:

```
// convex_hull_test.cpp:

#include <my_project/convex_hull.hpp>

using my_project::Point;

int main()
{
  Point<2> p1 = /* snip */;
  std::vector<Point<2> > xs = {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6};
  std::vector<size_t> hull = convex_hull(xs);

  /* snip */
  return 0;
}
```

Everything worked just fine, but the next day I looked at it again and realized that I should have written this line instead:

```
  std::vector<size_t> hull = my_project::convex_hull(xs);
```

because I never had `using my_project::convex_hull` anywhere. And yet I don't get any errors for using an undefined symbol when I compile this. **Why can I use this function without a namespace prefix**?

This is true for several other functions that I've defined. When I leave off the line `using my_project::Point;` I do get errors for using `Point` without namespace qualification. Are there different rules for functions, classes or templates about namespace qualification? Are the rules the same, indicating that there's something else weird going on?

I tried this with clang, g++ and icc, on more than one machine. I tried to construct a minimal test case, but the compiler threw the error that I thought it should in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the type of `xs` must have been available in the namespace `my_project`. What is happening is called [Argument-dependent lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

The C++ standard permits it. If you want to prevent ADL, try

```
std::vector<size_t> hull = (convex_hull)(xs);
```

Putting parentheses prevents argument-dependent lookup, try that, the compiler should complain.

**EDIT:** *based on OP's edit*

See Alan Stokes comment on this answer.

Comment: I should have been more explicit, `xs` is defined in the main program. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: `xs` must be of type `std::vector<Point<2> >`, which means the namespace in which `Point` is declared is an associated namespace, which is all that is needed for ADL to kick in.

Comment: Gotcha, I understand now!

Comment: Let this be a lesson - do not "snip"! Post a _complete_, minimal testcase! http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve